# Inverse Function for Banach Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I am learning about Calabi-Yau metrics on Kummer surfaces obtained by gluing Eguchi-Hanson spaces with a flat metric. In 'Calabi-Yau metrics on Kummer surfaces as a model glueing problem' Donaldson uses some inverse function theorem at the end of this paper to show that there is a solution in $L^2_5$ to the equation
\begin{equation}
\square f +h^{-3}Q(f)^2=h^3(\lambda(1+\eta)-1),
\end{equation}
whith $R,\lambda$ being a constant, $h,\eta$ functions and the non-linear differential operator $Q(f)$ has the property
\begin{equation}
\Vert (Rh)^{-3}(Q(g_1)^2-Q(g-2)^2)\Vert_{L^2_3}\leq C \Vert g_1-g_2\Vert_{L^2_5} (\Vert g_1 \Vert_{L^2_5}+\Vert g_2 \Vert_{L^2_5}).
\end{equation}
However i am not sure to 'which' inverse function theorem he is referring to. Is there any good reference for an inverse function thereom where the map is of the form
\begin{equation}
\Phi(x)=\Phi(0)+L(x)+N(x),
\end{equation}
whith $N$ non-linear, and $L$ having a right inverse?

Comment: Does this help you? Or do you need something more special https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Banach_spaces

Comment: I guess i need something more special, since the operator $\square$ has a one dimensional kernel and only a right inverse.